# Connecting to IRC

Tags: c, sockets, irc

I'm looking to write an IRC client in C, the trouble is I'm a bit of an IRC noob and I don't know exactly how IRC servers accept connections.

My English isn't too good, would someone be able to show me some pseudocode for an IRC connection?

Comment: Some not overly fun reading for you: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2812

Comment: Thanks, checking it out now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a TCP, line-based protocol. Just send something like this:

```
NICK MyNickname
USER MyUser 1 1 1 :I am awesome
```

Other than that, just respond to a `PING` with a corresponding `PONG`. Example:

> $ telnet irc.freenode.net 6667
> :morgan.freenode.net NOTICE * : Looking up your hostname...
> :morgan.freenode.net NOTICE * : Checking Ident
> :morgan.freenode.net NOTICE * : No Ident response
> :morgan.freenode.net NOTICE * : Found your hostname

I sent:

> NICK MyNickname
> USER MyUser 1 1 1 :I am awesome

I got:

> :morgan.freenode.net 001 MyNickname :Welcome to the freenode Internet Relay Chat Network MyNickname

The protocol is documented in [RFC1459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459). The biggest change since the RFC was released is that nicknames can now be longer, typically up to 30 characters.

Comment: Totally forgot about telnet. IRC seems to be much simpler than I thought. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Many servers won't finalise your registration if you don't respond the the PING :<id> request with your PONG :<id> reply. I got stumped with this in the past not knowing why my registration wouldn't progress.

Comment: @Troy: A long time ago, that was needed to protect against spoofed SYN attacks. If you could receive the `PING` and reply to it, that means you weren't spoofing your source address. Modern operating systems don't use predictable initial sequence numbers, so this is not needed anymore. But it's still around.

Comment: Some servers also won't let you log in unless your client is running an IDENTD server that the IRC server can query to verify that you are who you say you are and not someone spoofing the connection.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yeah. That's a relic from the time when most systems were multi-user. You won't find that much anymore.

Comment: The PING/PONG also protects against reflected connections created through FTP servers, connections by browsers tricked into it through crafted HTML forms, and a raft of similar attacks.

Comment: @caf: True. I can't think of an obvious way to make those attacks practical, but with the PING/PONG enabled, you don't even have to worry about it.